# Click on button keeping focus in textbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple calculator. I have buttons to write numbers in text boxes.

What I need to do is that when I choose text box 1 and click on buttons, numbers should be inputted in textbox 1 and when I choose textbox 2 and click on buttons, numbers should be inputted in textbox 2.

I have tried many different ways but nothing worked right, so if you have an idea how to solve this problem please write. Thx!

[image]

Comment: A fast way to do it (but for sure, not the best) is using `div`s instead of buttons or links and set a ngClick on them, then you won't lose the focus on the textbox when you click them.

Comment: OK, i'll try it.thx!

Comment: I've made a simple example using jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/wsd8ovm5/

Comment: Thanks! That looks good! I'll study that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking a little bit more I realised that its nonsense to use divs instead of buttons as I said in my comment on your question.

When we save the inputs in javascript variables we can work with their values and doesn't matter where is the focus.

Here is my jsfiddle updated using buttons wich is much more semantic: https://jsfiddle.net/wsd8ovm5/1/

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="btn">1</button>
    <button class="btn">2</button>
    <button class="btn">3</button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="btn">4</button>
    <button class="btn">5</button>
    <button class="btn">6</button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="btn">7</button>
    <button class="btn">8</button>
    <button class="btn">9</button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="btn">0</button>
</div>
<div>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="input1"/> <br>
    <input type="text" id="input1"/>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input1 = $('#input1'),
        input2 = $('#input1'),
        activeInput = input1;

    activeInput.focus(); //set focus

    $('input').on('focus', function(){
        //Save the last focused input
        activeInput = $(this);    
    });

    $('.btn').on('click', function(){
        //Append the button value, adding a empty string to prevent the sum of both values.
        activeInput.val(activeInput.val() + '' + $(this).text());

        //Convert the input value to float
        activeInput.val(parseFloat(activeInput.val()));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should "remember" which textarea had focus last (create handler for focus event for both textareas) than on click on any "number button", but the value of the button in the latest focused textarea. Be careful and just track focus event for first two textareas, the last one should be readonly.